# Error in using AdMob Plugin Pro

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, admob

I am new to iphone cordova.I want to use AdMob Plugin Pro, so i downloaded the zip file and then copied the .h and .m files to plugin folder and the AdMob.js to js folder inside the www folder.Then registered it in config.xml using the following lines

```
<plugin name="AdMob" value="AdMob" />
```

I have included the AdMob.js file in my index.html ,then i called the createBanner function defined in the AdMob.js but it gave me an error saying

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AdMob adMob plugin
```

The method which i called is as follows

```
 if(AdMob) {
        console.log('entered if babu');
        AdMob.createBanner( {
                             adId: id,
                             position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
                             autoShow: true } );
```

Can anyone guide me where possibly i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the admob plugin pro. The way you are using the plugin is not correct.

Instead of copying the files, please use the cordova command line tool to manage files for you:

```
[sudo] npm install cordova -g

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro
```

Here are the steps for quickly try the plugin with its sample index.html:

```
[sudo] npm install plugin-verify -g

plugin-verify cordova-plugin-admobpro
```

Then you will see the tool is creating a demo project, add the plugin, add ios/android platform, then build and run the app in emulator.

For more details, please check the wiki:
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki